# How to convert longitude and latitude string to double?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps

I'm getting my longitude and lattitude from google:

`http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Sliedrecht,%20Netherlands&output=csv&oe=utf8&sensor=false`

I want to add a marker to my map using this results:

```
        if (coordinates.Length == 4 && coordinates[0] == "200")
        {
            var overlay = new GMapOverlay(mapexplr, "overlayTwo");

            overlay.Markers.Add(new GMapMarkerGoogleGreen(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(coordinates[2]), Convert.ToDouble(coordinates[3]))));
            mapexplr.Overlays.Add(overlay);
        }
```

The problem is that my marker is not displayed. I think it is because the doubles aren't provided in the correct format. The result of the above link is this:

`200,4,51.8248681,4.7731624`

When I convert the value `4.7731624` to a double I get `47731624`, without the dot.

So my question is, how do I convert the string to a double with the dot in the right place?

Comment: You're using a [deprecated API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/index.html) - so you probably can't count on it working for too long. You should probably use the [current version of the geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Chances are it's due to your culture - it sounds like in this case you want the invariant culture:

```
double longitude = double.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(You may well want to use `double.TryParse` to gracefully handle the possibility of it not being a valid value.)

Comment: Yes, use TryParse, but initial the double to an invalid latitude/longitude value, so you know if it fails or not.

Comment: @twilson: The whole point of `TryParse` is that the *return* value tells you whether it's failed or not. The previous value of whatever you use for an `out` parameter is irrelevant - it'll be overwritten anyway.

Comment: Oops, my bad, for some reason that temporarily escaped me :P Oh the insanity.

Answer (score 0):

just use Double.Parse() and pass the string containing the lat/long coord

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` already uses `double.Parse` - but it will use the default culture, which won't work if it has a decimal separator of "," and a thousands separator of "." which is what I suspect is happening...

Comment: Thanks Jon! I didn't realize that the decimal separator in the Netherlands was different from ours in North America. Thanks again for the heads up!